# MYSQL: Calculate the SUM of a column grouped by two different conditions in a single query

Tags: mysql, sum

Say I have this simplified table structure with these sample data:

```
id | duration_seconds (int) | is_billable (boolean)
1  | 100                    | false
2  | 500                    | true
3  | 100                    | false
4  | 150                    | true
```

Is it possible to get a result like these from a single query?

```
total_duration | billable_duration | non_billable_duration
850            | 650               | 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the different sums in one query:

```
SELECT SUM(duration_seconds ) AS total_duration,
       SUM(CASE WHEN is_billable THEN duration_seconds ELSE 0 END) AS billable_duration,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT is_billable THEN duration_seconds ELSE 0 END) AS non_billable_duration
FROM yourtable
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
total_duration  billable_duration   non_billable_duration
850             650                 200
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d00f2a/2)